# webgl dash line

Tags: javascript, webgl

Can someone tell me how to draw dashed lines in WebGL without using Three.js or any other toolkit?  Just plain WebGL.  I'm very new to WebGL and I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

There are no native stippled lines in WebGL (or OpenGL ES) but the effect is easy to achieve with a fragment shader, if you include a "length so far" vertex attribute in your VBO.

```
precision highp float;
varying float LengthSoFar; // <-- passed in from the vertex shader
const vec3 Color = vec3(1, 1, 1);
const float NumDashes = 10.0; // 10 dashes for every 1 unit in LengthSoFar

void main()
{
    float alpha = floor(2.0 * fract(LengthSoFar * NumDashes));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(Color, alpha);
}
```

An alternative method would be to make a lookup into a 1D texture.  The length-so-far attribute is really just a 1D texture coordinate.

Comment: You could `discard` instead of alpha. Would probably be faster and not effect the zbuffer in the invisibile places.

Comment: Nice, I like the idea of using `discard`.

Comment: @prideout, How would the vertex shader calculate the `LengthSoFar` float? I don't know GLSL very well. Any leads?

Comment: @SuperScript, my answer suggested including `LengthSoFar` in the VBO, which means the CPU would compute it rather than the vertex shader.  Due to parallelism, vertex shaders cannot perform accumulation.

Answer (score 2):

Something that I've done in the past, though it may not meet your use case, is to create a vertex buffer containing the points of a path, then draw it using

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, vertexCount);
```

Using `gl.LINES` naturally "skips" every other segment of the path, creating a dashed effect if the path points are frequent enough. It's simple and hacky, but effective in the right circumstances.

Comment: I like this answer - its lazy in all the right ways! I think its worth pointing out how this trick works with data though - if you have an array of points: [a b c d e f ], then this will draw: a---b        c----d          e----f. so three dashes, two blanks (the blanks are between b and c and d and e, but StackOverflow seems to condense my whitespace in this comment, so its a bit hard to see.